# how to move values in a pandas column from some position to another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`

```
   df:
         A   I
  Time
    7    3   7
   14    2   6
   21    5   5
   28    7   2
   35    3   0
   42    0  23
   49   -1  28
```

I would like to move the last two values of `df['I']` in the column from position `Time=21` in order to have

```
   df:
         A   I
  Time
    7    3   7
   14    2   6
   21    5  23
   28    7  28
   35    3   5
   42    0   2
   49   -1   0
```

I tried the following

```
def swapper(tmp):
    tmp = tmp.reset_index(drop=True)
    tmp['I'][2:4] = tmp['I'][4:6]
    tmp['I'][4:6] = tmp['I'][2:4]
    return tmp
```

Comment: Is there some logic to why you want to move these values? Is this always the last two values to the rows 21 and 28, or can it also be something else?

Comment: @NielsHenkens I want just to shift the last two values in a given position of the dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No special Pandas way but you can do it like this:

```
def swapper(old, new, df, col_name):
    if len(old) != len(new):
        return "Lists must be equal"
    else:
        for i in zip(old,new):
            temp = df.loc[i[0], col_name]
            df.loc[i[0], col_name] = df.loc[i[1], col_name]
            df.loc[i[1], col_name] = temp
    return

swapper([21,28], [42,49], df, 'I')


    A   I
Time        
7   3   7
14  2   6
21  5   23
28  7   28
35  3   0
42  0   5
49  -1  2
```